# How do I make an automated task more advanced than a simple CRON job?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I currently have a script that takes 1,000 rows at a time from a MySQL table, loops through them, does some processing, easy stuff. Right now, though, it's not automated. Every time I want to run this, I connect with the terminal and just do php myscript.php and wait for it to end. The problem with this is that it's not fast enough - the processing the script does is scraping, and I have been asked to find out how to enable multiple instances of scraping at one time to speed things up.

So I started trying to plan out how to do this, and realized after a couple of Google searches that I honestly don't even know what the correct terminology for this actually is.

Am I looking to make a service with Apache? Or a daemon?

What I want my script to do is this:

1. Some kind of "controller" that looks up a main table, gets X rows (could be tens or hundreds of thousands) that haven't had a particular flag set
2. Counts the total of the result set, figures out how many "children" it would need in order to send rows in batches of, say, 5,000 to each of the "children"
3. Those "children" each get a group of rows. Say Child1 gets rows 0 - 5,000, Child2 gets rows 5,001 - 10,000, etc
4. After each "child" runs its batch of rows, it needs to tell the "controller" that it has finished, so the "controller" can then tell our Sphinx indexer to re-index, and then send a new batch of rows to the child that just completed (assuming there are still more rows to do)

My main concern here is with how to automate all of this, as well as how to get two or more PHP scripts to "talk" to each other, or at the very least, the children notifying the controller that they have finished and are awaiting new batches of rows.

Another concern I have is if I should be worried about MySQL database problems with these myriad scripts in terms of row-locking, or something similar? Or if the table the finished rows are going into is just using auto_increment, would this have the potential of conflicting ID numbers?

Comment: Have you tried starting the script in the background? You can then instantiate multiple script runs from the same terminal, no need to wait for the first to start the second.

Comment: A way would be to just run it in a cron every 20 minutes, and have it detach say 2 or 3 children who would each hit the database for the next set of rows needing to be run (have a column saying if the rows are checked out and when, if they've been checked out too long, reset them to not checked out.). Comment because you could probably do it better with a daemon.  Consider mine the "poor man's" choice.

Comment: @hakre Is there a difference between "starting it in the background" and me just typing, "php myscript.php" in the terminal? I'm a super-noob at this, I don't even know how to get started. :(

Comment: @Kinsbane: ´php myscript.php &´ - See as well [Bash: send a running process to background](http://www.smachado.com/2009/02/bash-send-a-running-process-to-background/). And there is [screen](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into turning that script into a daemon. With a bit of research and tinkering, you can get [`System_Daemon`<sup>­*Pear*</sup>](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon/) set up to do just that.

Here is an article that I used to help me write my first PHP daemon:

[Create daemons in PHP (09 Jan 2009; by Kevin van Zonneveld)](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/)

You can also consider the comment above, and run your script in the background, having the script run in a continuous loop indefinitely with a set wait timer, for example:

```
<?php
$timer=60; //after execution of the script, wait 60 seconds before running the script again
$fault=false;
while($fault==false) {
...YOUR SCRIPT CONTENTS HERE
//to kill your script, set $fault=true;
sleep $timer;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't know if it's just me, but your link isn't loading, not even Google's cache of it is coming up. I did find this: http://stuporglue.org/writing-a-daemon-with-php/ and I will look up "System_Daemon" as well to find more resources. Now that I know I was indeed looking for a daemon in PHP, it should be easier to build what I need. Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

When running multiple processes against a single queue I like using the following locking method to make sure that records are only processed by a single processor -

```
<?php

// retrieve the process id of the currently executing thread
$pid = getmypid();

// create the pseudo lock
$sql = "UPDATE queue_table SET pid_lock = '$pid' WHERE pid_lock IS NULL ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5000";

// retrieve the rows locked by the previous query
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, etc FROM queue_table WHERE pid_lock = '$pid'";
```

This works quite nicely but it should be noted that process IDs are not unique and collisions are possible but for many situations they are adequate for simple locking.  To reduce the likelihood of a collision you could combine the pid with a timestamp.  Depending on how long it takes to process an individual row you may be better off running much smaller batches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Once I figure out exactly how to run multiple processes in Apache for PHP scripts I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like Gearman (http://gearman.org/) would do what you need. You'd start the process whoever you choose (manually, cron, or whatever else suits your needs). That process would then query the database and create workers that would perform the scraping tasks in parallel.

You could also accomplish it by forking PHP processes (pcntl_fork()) but then you'd have to create your own mechanism for them to communicate with the parent process. You can watch the PIDs to see when they are complete, but to get more elaborate info the workers would have to store their results in an easily accessible location (DB, memcache, etc.).

Comment: I want to give you a vote, but you'll have to settle for a "THANK YOU!!!!" instead. I'll look up Gearman and see what I can do with it.